# Can recursion have an endless loop?

Tags: recursion, iteration, infinite-loop, infinite-recursion

I hear people say a lot of times recursion can be an “endless loop”, but wouldn’t that saying be only applied to something done with loops. Would it be valid and correct to say “endless loop” for recursion like that? Wouldn’t it better to say “endless recursion”?

Comment: Personally, I've always considered recursion to be a form of looping. Recursion can achieve the same job as a built-in looping construct.

Comment: @Carcigenicate while recursion can have the same surface-effect as loop, I would very strongly disagree, that *recursion is a form of looping*. Recursion has completely different execution semantic, memory usage, and even aims/problems to solve. There are plenty of examples, where recursion seems to be doing kind of "loop logic", however, you can't achieve the same that easily with loop, and vice versa.

Comment: @wisemovi recursion will be infinite, if you don't define properly the base case, or if you have some other infinity problem in any of recursive branches. Recursion is quite often overused, in the examples, where they shouldn't be used. It uses plenty of memory. I didn't understand the rest of your question.. so, sorry.

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri I see looping as just the task of repeating code. I don't think memory usage or the exact implementation of each are relevant to the definition.

Comment: @Carcigenicate and how do you decide which to use and when (traditional loop or recursive approach)? based on what criteria?

Comment: @GiorgiTsiklauri If the problem is recursive (like dealing with a recursive structure), and I have guarantees about the "size" of the problem, I'll use recursion until there's reason to believe that it's a problem.

Answer (score 1):

A tail recursion can be considered a iterative loop. This is the only type of infinite recursion that doesn't swiftly end with a stack overflow error.

If you write this in a compliant ECMAScript 2016 implementation

```
const test = (n) => test(n + 1);
test(0);
```

It will hang forever and never cause a stack overflow. The browser will hang as it is a busy loop, but it will never get a stack overflow because tail calls are optimized into something like this:

```
const test = (n) => {
  while(true) {
    n++;
  }
}
test(0);
```

If you consider the bottom one an infinite loop, the first one is not different.
If this was C both would be turning into very similar assembly code using gotos, because assembly does not have while loops nor functions.